# ImportError: No module named MySQLdb due to MariaDB libs

Tags: python, mysql

I'm new to python, trying to connect python with MYSQL, i'm unable to import the MYSQLdb module, i was able to install python-dev, i'm having issues with MySQL-python rpm. this rpm requires libmysqlclient.so.18() as dependency.

```
[root@test tmp]# rpm -ivh MySQL-python-1.2.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-python-1.2.5-        
1.el7.x86_64
    libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) is needed by MySQL-
python-1.2.5-1.el7.x86_64
[root@test tmp]#
```

When i try to install the libmysqlclient.so.18, it says mariadb-libs will be installed, but maria-db conflicts with MYSQL server, i'm not sure how to proceed further.

```
[root@test tmp]# yum install libmysqlclient.so.18
Loaded plugins: langpacks, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-
repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-rpms                                                                                                                                                                                                    
| 2.1 kB  00:00:00
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.1-rpms                                                                                                                                                                                
| 2.1 kB  00:00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.i686 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.i686 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 - u due to obsoletes from             
installed MySQL-shared-compat-5.6.37-1.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.i686 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
[root@test tmp]#
```

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 and Python 2.7.5 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you done `yum install mysql mysql-server`?

Comment: I installed the mysql server and client thorugh RPM method. MySQL-server-5.6.34-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and MySQL-client-5.6.34-1.el7.x86_64.rpm is installed, they are running without any issues. I'm able to access the DB and create database.

Comment: I would try uninstalling everything and reinstall using `yum` package manager. It does version checking for you to make sure all the versions match.